# Android ListView TouchListener called on scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll, ontouchlistener

In my project I have a `ListView` which has a `touchListener` in `getView` method from `adapter` for each view.

My problem is that the `touchListener` activates when I scroll the list.

How could I **disable** the touch when the user scrolls the list, regarding that the listener is set on `getView()` method?

Thanks

UPDATE:
The code from list adapter looks like this:

```
  package com.example;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList){

        mListItems = arrayList;

        //get the layout inflater
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //getCount() represents how many items are in the list
        return mListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    //get the data of an item from a specific position
    //i represents the position of the item in the list
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    //get the position id of the item from the list
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
        if (view == null) {
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ON TOUCH ACTIVATED", 0).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
        String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);
        if (stringItem != null) {

            TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);

            if (itemName != null) {
                //set the item name on the TextView
                itemName.setText(stringItem);
            }
        }

        //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `onClick` instead of `onTouch`?

Comment: AFAIK, the android platform has this built-in property for lists, so something is wrong with your code. Please edit the question and put your code in.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the code from my custom adapter. I have tried to return false and true for the onTouchListener, but no result :(. I got the code for the listview from http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/07/android-listview-tutorial.html and I put the listener for touch, if you want to test and see yourself what is happening you can get the code from there too.

Comment: You really should look into using `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` or `OnClickListener` on each `View`.

Comment: The problem is that I have to use onTouchListener because I need the MotionEvent for the next features that I have to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem after all, by adding in the xml layout where the ListView is declared this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and it's working now.